# How do we use SELECT query with an external WHERE parameter in rusqlite?

Tags: rust, rusqlite

I need to fetch a row from a database using SELECT and WHERE, I need to fetch a row depending on the age, I tried this way using some other tutorial.

```
use rusqlite::{params, Connection, Result};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    data: String,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let conn = Connection::open_in_memory()?;

    conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE person (
                  id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                  name            TEXT NOT NULL,
                  age           INTEGER,
                  data            TEXT
                  )",
        [],
    )?;
    let me = Person {
        id: 0,
        name: "Steven".to_string(),
        age:1,
        data: "data1".to_string(),
    };
    conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO person (name, age, data) VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3)",
        params![me.name, me.age, me.data],
    )?;

    conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO person (name, age, data) VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3)",
        params!["john".to_string(), 2, "data2".to_string()],
    )?;
    
    let age:u8 = 1;
    
    let mut stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT id, name, age, data FROM person WHERE age=:age;")?;
    let person_iter = stmt.query_map([], |row| {
        Ok(Person {
            id: row.get(0)?,
            name: row.get(1)?,
            age: row.get(2)?,
            data: row.get(3)?,
        })
    })?;

    for person in person_iter {
        println!("Found person {:?}", person);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

How do we use SELECT query with an external WHERE parameter?

Comment: You mean this: https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.25.0/rusqlite/struct.Statement.html#use-with-named-params ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `params` of `query_map()` for this like that:

```rust
stmt.query_map(&[(":age", age.to_string().as_str())], |row| { ... }
```

Full working sample based on your code in the question:

```rust
use rusqlite::{params, Connection, Result};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    data: String,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let conn = Connection::open_in_memory()?;

    conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE person (
                  id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                  name            TEXT NOT NULL,
                  age           INTEGER,
                  data            TEXT
                  )",
        [],
    )?;
    let me = Person {
        id: 0,
        name: "Steven".to_string(),
        age:1,
        data: "data1".to_string(),
    };
    conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO person (name, age, data) VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3)",
        params![me.name, me.age, me.data],
    )?;

    conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO person (name, age, data) VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3)",
        params!["john".to_string(), 2, "data2".to_string()],
    )?;
    
    let age:u8 = 1;
    
    let mut stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT id, name, age, data FROM person WHERE age=:age;")?;
    let person_iter = stmt.query_map(&[(":age", age.to_string().as_str())], |row| {
        Ok(Person {
            id: row.get(0)?,
            name: row.get(1)?,
            age: row.get(2)?,
            data: row.get(3)?,
        })
    })?;

    for person in person_iter {
        println!("Found person {:?}", person);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: One can also use `&x.to_string()` instead of `x.to_string().as_str()`.

Comment: You can also simply use `age`, rusqulite converts the `u8` to the appropriate sqlite datatype for you.